# How to sum values from two iterator "lists"?

Tags: python, iterator

I have two iterators, which consists of a "list" that looks something like this:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
 [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
 [3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 19],
 [5, 9, 1, 9, 4, 6]]
```

Or, that is what it will look like if I just ran a `for` loop over them.

The reason for the iterator and not a list per se is due to memory. The true lists/arrays are way larger, this is just an example.
What I need to do is take one list and sum the columns of each index inside the list for all "outside" indices and then add them together for both lists like `sum(list1) + sum(list2)`.

So basically:

```
list1:                   list2:
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],     [[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9],
 [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],    [6, 3, 8, 1, 1, 6],  
 [3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 19],     [1, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3],
 [5, 9, 1, 9, 4, 6]]      [5, 2, 9, 4, 2, 5]]
          =>                       =>
 [11, 20, 18, 20, 43]     [17, 12, 22, 15, 23]
                       =>
              [28, 32, 40, 35, 66]
```

So I iterate over the two lists, and for each list I need to sum the columns, and then in the end at the columns of the final two lists into one combined list.

I know how to do this if it were just regular lists, but since this is iterators/generators (don't know the correct term) I am really not sure how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to sum each one without loading everything into memory:

```
def sumIter(iter):
    result = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #Assuming there are always 6 items in each sub-list
    for list in iter:
       result = [(result[i] + list[i]) for i in range(6)]
```

And then:

```
sum1 = sumIter(iter1)
sum2 = sumIter(iter2)
result = [(sum1[i] + sum2[i]) for i in range(6)]
```

Comment: There is always a fixed size items in each list, but the number of lists can differ. So in my example in OP, both lists have 4 rows. But in reality one could have 3 and another 6. Would this still work ?

Comment: Yes, the summing function will work for any number of sub-lists. The loop (`for list in iter`) iterates the generator all the way to the end. One caveat, if there is no end (like `itertools.count` never ends) then the loop will never exit, so be careful with your generators.

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip`

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
    [3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 19],
    [5, 9, 1, 9, 4, 6]
]
l2 = [
    [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9],
    [6, 3, 8, 1, 1, 6],
    [1, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3],
    [5, 2, 9, 4, 2, 5]
]


l1 = (sum(i) for i in zip(*l1))
l2 = (sum(i) for i in zip(*l2))

print( [sum(i) for i in zip(l1, l2)] )
```

**Output:**

```
[28, 32, 40, 42, 26, 66]
```

Comment: But this works for lists only, right ? I have iterators. That should make a difference.

Comment: It should work on iterators also...You can test using `l1 = iter(l1)
l2 = iter(l2)`

Answer (score 0):

Using `reduce` since row can be added in numpy array.

`reduce` is an build-in function in python2

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce # only in python3

def sumup(one_row, another_row):
   return one_row + another_row

test_list = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12],
                   [3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 19], 
                   [5, 9, 1, 9, 4, 6]])

reduce(sumup, test_list)
```

Output

```
array([11, 20, 18, 27, 20, 43])
```

Answer (score 0):

using [numpy.sum](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html)

```
import numpy as np

l1 = np.sum([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12], [3, 5, 8, 6, 1, 19], [5, 9, 1, 9, 4, 6]], axis=0)
l2 = np.sum([[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 9],[6, 3, 8, 1, 1, 6], [1, 3, 2, 8, 2, 3],[5, 2, 9, 4, 2, 5]], axis=0)

print(l1 + l2)
```

**Output**

```
[28 32 40 42 26 66]
```

Comment: But this works for lists only, right ? I have iterators. That should make a difference.